# Is there an ansible/salt/chef like thing for simple personal use?

Tags: linux, macos, package-management

I find myself wanting to codify my coding environment - packages, dotfiles, vim/emacs plugins etc. I currently host my dotfiles on github, and it would be awesome to have a way to have required packages also specified. If my dotfiles and editor plugins rely on certain tools being installed, I don't want to rediscover these every time I start using a new machine.

Beyond hand-rolling bash scripts to call brew on Mac and yum on Linux, are there accepted alternatives? What if some tools require a build from source and are not available on yum?

I like the idea of docker images, but I feel like it's a layer too much - I want these tools installed directly on my machine. (You could probably sway me somewhat)

Thanks!

Comment: ansible is good for a single machine configuration.